# Netbeans 8 IDE Services tab SQlite3 Database connection error

Tags: java, netbeans, sqlite

In the Netbeans version 8 using the Java language under Services,  when I right click on the connection I have setup I keep getting this error

> Unable to connect. Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlite:blah.db using org.sqlite.JDBC (opening db 'blah.db': Access is denied).

I am on windows 7.  I have checked the permissions of the database file and there is no reason not to access the file.

Netbeans can find the file so the url setting is working.

NO user name or password is set on the database.

I can by use of code open the database and execute a query.   The reason behind doing this via netbeans, is to bind a control to the SQLite database.

Does anybody have any ideas why I would get an Access Denied error other than a permissions issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: blah.db doesn't appear to be a full path. Maybe its looking in the wrong directory for the file. Your code could be running in a different directory than the netbeans main process.

Comment: Actually I found this on another site:  https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/2lcy6r/sqlite_and_javarmi_javasqlsqlexception_error/

Comment: The issue appears to be  "JAAS permissions"  .  I do know the url path does work and this is because of a previous error I was getting.  Access Denied would indicate a permissions issue. I have attempted  to add  create=true to the end of the path.  No luck.